# Adding a Google Map on my meteor app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor

So I'm trying to convert a static website I've made to work as a meteor app, instead of having 5 html files to each store, plus multiple html standard pages, I got them all to "one" single html file using directives, problem is when I'm trying to insert the map on the website, for some reason it doesn't work, I've tried multiple things but still couldn't make a standard map appear on the page, let alone a customised version..

here I'm just defining the map on the html file (the id I will change later to show the map I want for each store or just change the lat lng based on the store I'm currently showing on the page):

```
<div id="mapCS" class="map col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
</div>
```

this is the js file I used on the static version of the website and its working as intended (on the static version obviously):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCS"),
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        map: map,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        title: 'Savoie Volailles Cranves Sales',
        icon: {
            url:"img/logo.png",
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 64),
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        // 0.1 seconds after the center of the map has changed,
        // set back the marker position.
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            marker.setPosition(myCenter);
        }, 100);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I also had a script tag to insert my api key..

Comment: What package are you using to incorporate Google maps into your Meteor app? I am also going to do that. I haven't started on that part yet, but plan on using dburles:google-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [angularui:angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) as recomended [here](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/google-maps)

Just add the dependency and call it with a directive. Configuring the options is very easy and done from the controller

Comment: Never mind just got it! I was calling the wrong options on my directive.. lol

Comment: I don't understand one thing, my map is working in all my html files, except the one file I need, it gets grey for some reason..
is it because I'm using a ng-repeat?
Also, can I use my options like this:

{<ui-gmap-google-map center="{{magasin.map.center}}" //can i use it like this or i don't need to use curly braces?
                        zoom="magasin.zoom">

    </ui-gmap-google-map>}

Comment: If it worked for you could you accept the answer please?

Comment: Why are you begging for me to accept your answer? The map worked, but not completely, thats why I didn't close this question yet..

Comment: I am asking for you to follow the rules of this site not begging. I did not see any real showstopper in your comment. So what is failing with  angularui:angular-google-maps? if you update your code I will check if I can help of course you should not use curly braces

Comment: if I put my code in all my html template files, it works, but for some reason it doesn't work in my maps page template.. The map gets all grey.. it should be a scope issue, but since I don't much of scope related issues on angular i guess i need to look for the docs a little bit deeper, thanks anyway! oh and the curly braces was to insert the code, but messed it up lol